# Extract PATH from filename

Tags: linux, bash, shell, awk, sed

A list (*without the **.ABC** and **.DEF** extentions!*) of more than 100.000 files needs to be copied.
At the moment I'm using **while** combined with **find** command in the **/opt/project/** directory to generate the full PATH so I can copy them later.

```
while read LINE; do find opt/project/TOP3RST_0_/ -name "$LINE"*; done <  < TOP3RST_0_file.list > PATH_TOP3RST_0_file.list
```

This process is going to slowly. I wonder if I can use awk, sed or something else to create the full PATH from the file list. Also if I can check if each file does exist would be a bonus.

**From this**:

*BT_SUPR_TOP3RST_0__20200716T004902_20200716T005113_0002
BT_SUPR_TOP3RST_0__20200716T005308_20200716T005352_0002
BT_SUPR_TOP3RST_0__20200716T005653_20200716T005748_0002
BT_SUPR_TOP3RST_0__20200716T005752_20200716T005824_0002
BT_SUPR_TOP3RST_0__20200716T010842_20200716T011051_000*2

**Expected output PATH should be like this**:

```
/opt/project/TOP3RST_0_/2020/07/16/BT_SUPR_TOP3RST_0__20200716T004902_20200716T005113_0002/BT_SUPR_TOP3RST_0__20200716T004902_20200716T005113_0002.ABC

/opt/project/TOP3RST_0_/2020/07/16/BT_SUPR_TOP3RST_0__20200716T004902_20200716T005113_0002/BT_SUPR_TOP3RST_0__20200716T004902_20200716T005113_0002.DEF

/opt/project/TOP3RST_0_/2020/07/16/BT_SUPR_TOP3RST_0__20200716T005308_20200716T005352_0002/BT_SUPR_TOP3RST_0__20200716T005308_20200716T005352_0002.ABC

/opt/project/TOP3RST_0_/2020/07/16/BT_SUPR_TOP3RST_0__20200716T005308_20200716T005352_0002/BT_SUPR_TOP3RST_0__20200716T005308_20200716T005352_0002.DEF

/opt/project/TOP3RST_0_/2020/07/16/BT_SUPR_TOP3RST_0__20200716T005653_20200716T005748_0002/BT_SUPR_TOP3RST_0__20200716T005653_20200716T005748_0002.ABC

/opt/project/TOP3RST_0_/2020/07/16/BT_SUPR_TOP3RST_0__20200716T005653_20200716T005748_0002/BT_SUPR_TOP3RST_0__20200716T005653_20200716T005748_0002.DEF

/opt/project/TOP3RST_0_/2020/07/16/BT_SUPR_TOP3RST_0__20200716T005752_20200716T005824_0002/BT_SUPR_TOP3RST_0__20200716T005752_20200716T005824_0002.ABC

/opt/project/TOP3RST_0_/2020/07/16/BT_SUPR_TOP3RST_0__20200716T005752_20200716T005824_0002/BT_SUPR_TOP3RST_0__20200716T005752_20200716T005824_0002.DEF

/opt/project/TOP3RST_0_/2020/07/16/BT_SUPR_TOP3RST_0__20200716T010842_20200716T011051_0002/BT_SUPR_TOP3RST_0__20200716T010842_20200716T011051_0002.ABC

/opt/project/TOP3RST_0_/2020/07/16/BT_SUPR_TOP3RST_0__20200716T010842_20200716T011051_0002/BT_SUPR_TOP3RST_0__20200716T010842_20200716T011051_0002.DEF
```

Last I need the calculation of the gap in time:

BT_SUPR_TOP3RST_0__20200716T003457_20100716T004736_0002.ABC

20200716T003457 = 2020-07-16 00:34:57

20200716T004736 = 2020-07-16 00:47:36

I reckon something like [datediff](http://www.fresse.org/dateutils/#datediff) can calculate the gap?

Comment: Tl;dr, please. What's the sample data and what's the expected output? You lost me there,

Comment: Have you read [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) ? Lost too. Alway try to simplify/minify the issue

Comment: Do I have this right?  Your process is given a filename and only a filename.  You don't where that file is, but the full path is encoded in the filename.  So you have to parse the file name to figure out where it's located?  And that parsing is too slow?  But the process that created that file has to know where it is?  But only passes the filename?  **Change the creating process to pass the entire path.**  That way the file name doesn't have to repeat information contained in the path - that's useless redundancy.

Comment: This is really difficult to read. Could you add a better description of your problem? where do you read the paths from? is it a text file? Can you also provide the full snippet?

Comment: `"$LINE"*` is strange, you want `"$LINE*"`. `This process is going to slowly` Sure it is - you are running `find` 100000 times... Run __one__ `find` will all the `-name .. -o -name othername -o -name anothername etc.`. `but I need the full PATH to locate` Why? Just add `"$PWD/` to find argument. Anyway, you started your post with copying some files. Then you posted some `find` execution command line. Then you posted some lines that need a suffix and a prefix to be added. Is it all related? You want to speed that `find` or create a list with `.ABC` `.DEF` extensions?

Comment: All, thanks for showing interest.
James,Gilles and Armando I have updated my question. Hopefully it's a bit clearer.
KamilCuk, I will try to improve the find command but essentially I don't want to use find since the directory structure is the same /year/month/date/filename/
I wonders if I can extract the PATH from the filename and generate a list with the full path I can copy the files.

Comment: @AndrewHenle the creating process was done by another team in the database. These files are the result of that process that are located in the storage. I do agree it would be easier but I have to find these files at this moment

Comment: @sacdeb LOL.  The cluelessness that implies is risible.  "We can't put the entire path into the database, that would take too much space!"  In the era of multi-***terabyte*** drives that cost under $100, they spent who knows how many man-hours coming up with a solution that uses 75-character filenames to do something like ***save space***?!?!?!  They wasted who knows how many expensive hours, probably used more space, and made everyones' work harder.  I bet they thought they were being smart, too.  Except they didn't think it all the way through, did they?

Comment: @AndrewHenle not really. To be honest the issue is and always has been with management. They haven't invested in our department for years but still want to have the same results. COVID19 has seen our team shrink so we are just doing what we can. Something that is similar in most companies. At this point you have to let somethings fail so they see the value in it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following `sed` line may let you get started:

```
$ sed 's@.*__\([0-9]\{4\}\)\([0-9]\{2\}\)\([0-9]\{2\}\).*@/opt/project/TOP3RST_0_/\1/\2/\3/&/&@; s/.*/&.ABC\n&.DEF/' <<<'BT_SUPR_TOP3RST_0__20200716T004902_20200716T005113_0002'
/opt/project/TOP3RST_0_/2020/07/16/BT_SUPR_TOP3RST_0__20200716T004902_20200716T005113_0002/BT_SUPR_TOP3RST_0__20200716T004902_20200716T005113_0002.ABC
/opt/project/TOP3RST_0_/2020/07/16/BT_SUPR_TOP3RST_0__20200716T004902_20200716T005113_0002/BT_SUPR_TOP3RST_0__20200716T004902_20200716T005113_0002.DEF
```

The whole line is matched with the year, month and day saved with backreferences. Then the proper pattern is generated. With a second `s` command two lines are outputted with different suffix. For learning regexes I recommend regex crosswords available on the net. [This](https://www.grymoire.com/Unix/Sed.html) sed introduction is great, but here only `s` command is used. FAQ: `&` is the whole matched pattern and `s` command may take any character as delimiter.